# Module cross reference design issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python file called `testlib.py`, its intention is defined some utility class and global function used by other modules. The `uselib.py` is designed as a client which is using class/global functions from `testlib.py`.

Dues to some design issues, `testlib.py` needs to refer to some class `Goo` defined in `uselib.py`. If I just import directly, there will be error message (post below).

Just wondering how to handle this situation for cross reference elegantly in Python 2.7

**uselib.py**,

```
import testlib

class Goo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def checkValue(self):
        return "check value in Goo"

print testlib.globalFoo()
f = testlib.Foo()
print f.getValue()
```

**testlib.py**,

```
import uselib

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def getValue(self):
        g = uselib.Goo()
        g.checkValue()
        return 'get value in class Foo'

def globalFoo():
    return 'in global foo'
```

**Error Message**,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/personal/uselib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import testlib
  File "/Users/foo/personal/testlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import uselib
  File "/Users/foo/personal/uselib.py", line 9, in <module>
    print testlib.globalFoo()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'globalFoo'
```

Comment: You have a circular import. `Goo` does not need to be contained in `uselib` from what I can tell

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks and what do you mean not needed? It is already defined in uselib.py, which I cannot change or move.

Comment: Circular imports, and more generally, circular dependencies of any sort, are quite often a strong indicator that something needs to be redesigned...

Comment: @twalberg, any specific advice to resolve the design issues in my use case?

Comment: @LinMa Well, as cricket_007 pointed out, there's no reference to `Goo` in `uselib.py`, so there's no reason for it to be defined there, and it could just as easily be moved into `testlib.py`. You state you can't do that, but don't explain the reason. I guess we'd need a more complete example to see what the best solution is...

Comment: @twalberg, class `Goo` is owned by some other parties, which I cannot move by myself's willingness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a sneaky hack: only `import testlib` when you are already calling the `__main__` function in `uselib.py`. Using the check `if __name__ == "__main__"` in `uselib.py` is important in this case. That way, you avoid the circular importing. The `testlib.py` has all the classes in `uselib.py`, but `uselib.py` only loads everything in `testlib.py` when it needs calling them.

Code for **uselib.py**:

```
#import testlib

class Goo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def checkValue(self):
        return "check value in Goo"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import testlib
    print testlib.globalFoo()
    f = testlib.Foo()
    print f.getValue()
```

Code for **testlib.py**:

```
import uselib

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def getValue(self):
        g = uselib.Goo()
        g.checkValue()
        return 'get value in class Foo'

def globalFoo():
    return 'in global foo'
```

Output:

```
Chip chip@ 04:00:00@ ~: python uselib.py
in global foo
get value in class Foo
```

Note that: `import testlib` could also be called in any arbitary function in `uselib.py`, and it doesnot need to be `__main__`. E.g.:

Code for another **uselib.py**:

```
#import testlib

class Goo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def checkValue(self):
        return "check value in Goo"
def moretest():
   import testlib
   print testlib.globalFoo()
   f = testlib.Foo()
   print f.getValue()

#if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import testlib
    #print testlib.globalFoo()
    #f = testlib.Foo()
    #print f.getValue()
```

Code for **stackoverflow.py**:

```
import uselib
uselib.moretest()
```

Calling **stackoverflow.py**:

```
Chip chip@ 04:30:06@ ~: python stackoverflow.py
in global foo
get value in class Foo
```

Comment: Thanks Tuan333, smart idea. If I need to refer functions and class defined in testlib outside main, any solutions?

Comment: you could try to `import` *inside* the function in `uselib.py`  where you actually need stuff form `testlib.py`. The function in which you call `import testlib` does not need to be `__main__`